# How to set a state array with values from TextField using onchange

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and am trying to add string values in an array. I am using Material-UI objects.

My state has

```
this.state: {
  roles: []
}
```

A button pushes an undefined element in roles, incrementing its length.

```
  clickAddRole = () => {
    this.setState({roles: this.state.roles.concat([undefined]) });
  };
```

So now we have some length to the roles array.
The Textfield is generated with

```
      this.state.roles.map((item, i)=> {
        return (
          <TextField id={'roles['+i+']'} label={'role '+i} key={i} onChange={this.handleChange('roles['+i+']')}  />
        )
      })
```

the onchange event is handled as below

```
  handleChange = name => event => {
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.roles);
  }
```

The console.log statements generate output like

```
roles[0]
[undefined]
```

I expect

```
roles[0]
["somedata"]
```

what is going wrong here? The data does not get set in the roles array.

The whole code file is

```
const styles = theme => ({
  error: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 300
  },
  submit: {
    margin: 'auto',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
})

class AddModule extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      roles:[],
      open: false,
      error: ''
    }
  }

  clickSubmit = () => {
    const module = {
      roles: this.state.roles || undefined
    }
    create(module).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        this.setState({error: data.error})
      } else {
        this.setState({error: '', 'open': true});
      }
    })
  }

  clickAddRole = () => {
    this.setState({roles: this.state.roles.concat([undefined]) });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.roles);
  }
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
            <Button onClick={this.clickAddRole} >Add Role</Button>
            {
              this.state.roles.map((item, i)=> {
                return (
                  <TextField className={classes.textField} id={'roles['+i+']'} label={'role '+i} key={i} onChange={this.handleChange('roles['+i+']')}  />
                )
              })
            }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of the render function for the `this.state.roles.map` please?

Comment: You merged an array [undefined], which has an element 'undefined'.

Comment: Okay sir.... I have added the whole file at the bottom now. basically I have a lot to do but first I am testing if this method works. The state has an empty array called roles. The user can add an extra element to the row which is undefined initially. Then he gets an extra row of textfield to add the new role. the onchange event updates the state of roles with the new data. This is my concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into my request. I am new to such forums. So, my apologies if I am doing something wrong. please do guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making the whole code a bit overcomplicated creating names for each input field. What I would do is change the `handleRolesChange` or `handleChange` (not really sure if you changed its name) method so that it takes the `index` instead of a `name`.

```
handleRolesChange = index => event => {
  const { roles } = this.state;
  const newRoles = roles.slice(0); // Create a shallow copy of the roles
  newRoles[index] = event.target.value; // Set the new value
  this.setState({ roles: newRoles });
}
```

Then change the render method to something like this:

```
this.state.roles.map((item, index) => (
  <TextField 
    id={`roles[${index}]`}
    label={`role ${index}`}
    key={index}
    onChange={this.handleRolesChange(index)}  
  />
))
```

Comment: Brilliant simply Brilliant !!! It worked very smoothly... Thanks a million. 5 hours of struggle :) for me.

Comment: @Avinash I'm happy to hear that! Glad to help you out :D

Answer (score 0):

Guy I have the issue (maybe temporarily). 
I an array-element is a child of the array. so changing the data in the array-element does not need setState.

So this is what I did....

```
  handleRolesChange = name => event => {
    const i = [name];
    this.state.roles[i]=event.target.value;
  }
```

I also change the Textfield onchange parameter to
onChange={this.handleRolesChange(i)}
where i is the index starting from zero in the map function.

All this works perfectly as I needed.
However, if you think that I have mutated the roles array by skipping setState, I will keep the Question unanswered and wait for the correct & legitimate answer.

Thanks a lot for your support guys.
We must try and find the solution for such basic issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive it's not being set? From React's [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

Usually logging state in the same block you set the code in will print the **previous** state, since state has not actually updated at the time the console.log fires.

I would recommend using [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to check state, instead of relying on console.log.